# Laravel Uploaded File Not Accessible Through Browser

Tags: laravel, upload, filesystems

I am using Laravel 5.7. I can upload files to my system with a form that I created. I am having a hard time making them accessible to the users of the system. How do I do that? I keep getting 404 errors.

My filesystem driver

```
    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),
```

this saves all files to "storage/app/public",

```
        foreach ($request->attachments as $attachment) {
            $originalname = $attachment->getClientOriginalName();
            $ext = $attachment->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $formattedname = "doc$doc->id-$i.$ext";
            $filepath = $attachment->storeAs("pdocs/customers/$customer/projects/$projectid/tr", $formattedname);
            ReviewAttachment::create([
                'customer_id' => $customer,
                'project_id' => $projectid,
                'user_id' => $user,
                'filepath' => $filepath,
                'filename' => $originalname,
            ]);
            $i++;
        }
```

Then show the link from that saved attachment as below:

```
<a href="{{Storage::disk('public')->url('$attachment->filepath')}}"> View </a>
```

1. How can I access those files through the browser?
2. Can someone clarify the difference between public and local drives option in driver system? They both save the files on my local system --- which one should I be using if I want to show links of uploaded files to the user who uploaded them or people with permission who can view these uploaded file? Public means open to web for everyone or I need to use "public" to make the files available.

Comment: Have you created the symlink between the public folder and the local storage? `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: I just did that links started working with below code;
```<a href="{{Storage::disk('local')->url('$attachment->filepath')}}"> View </a> ```

I am confused about being local and public? what's the difference here?

Comment: the public folder is basically a folder that according to your server config is reachable from the outside (WWW), local is basically a way of saying that the storage is the same instance than the one the app is running, the command you just ran, create a symbolic link in your public folder to the folder in which according to local disk config laravel will save the files.

So it's just about the wording.